# UK visa refused under V 4.2 a c

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas, proof-provenance-of-funds

[image][image]

I was exhibiting in a health sector expo and trade fair in Great Britain along with my father and my father already had a visa.

My company have given me the funds and these are in my account. The company bank statement is more than 1 million and the money I am spending is given by the company and family which is shown through my bank statement.

Should I get the administrative view or should I reapply?

Comment: Why did your father's application say he wasn't traveling with anyone if you planned to travel together? It's certainly possible that you guys changed your minds after his application, but it clearly appeared suspicious, if not dishonest, to the ECO. Are you able to document the source of the recent large deposits into your personal bank account to show you aren't trying to inflate your balance for this application?

Comment: you can't claim business funds as your own money. your company may fund your costs if the trip is for business, but you should have your own personal bank account showing salary paid in and living costs (rent/mortgage/bills etc) coming out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem I don't think you can address easily: your father's visa was probably issued on the basis that, among other things, his family members (you) would remain at home. The visa officer thinks you don't have enough ties to home and so might overstay in the UK.

Comment: I Have applied for Poland exhibition  central European dental exhibition and UK health GB which I am refused how should I apply for Poland under these circumstances
My show is on 22 September.

Comment: I would consider using a lawyer with expertise in Polish visas. Do a basic cost/benefit analysis: compare the cost in lawyers fees to the likely value of business gained by attending the event.