# I have been refused for UK visa under V 4.2 A C Should I apply for poland visa?

Tags: visas, uk, schengen, visa-refusals, poland

I Have applied for Poland exhibition  central European dental exhibition and UK health GB which I am refused how should I apply for Poland under these circumstances
My show is on 22 September I have paid the exhibition fees.
[image][image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UK visa refusal on V 4.2 a + c (and sometimes 'e')](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e).  You've [already asked](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/112523/uk-visa-refused-under-v-4-2-a-c) this question, and had it closed as a duplicate of our canonical question on UK V4.2a,c refusals.  Please don't keep asking it again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- A refusal from the UK does not cause an automatic refusal from Poland.
- The reasons which led the UK to refuse your visa may also lead Poland to refuse your visa, or they may not.
- You may be able to to prepare an application which explains the financial transactions to the Polish authorities if you have a good explanation.
- Poland may be less concerned than the UK about Pakistani citizens coming to overstay because there is less of a Pakistani community there.

You may try it **if** you have a logical explanation for the money movement, but there is always a risk that Poland will find that suspicious, too.